# React native app crashes when opening push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native, react-native-push-notification

my react-native keeps crashing when I try to open a push notification on android. I am using `firebase` for the notification but using `react-native-push-notification` to open the notification. Please might I be doing wrong? I am using only on useLinking. This is the error I get when you try to open the notification on my android. PLease why should i do?

[image]